# Usage Data Collection for JavaScript Mobile Apps

Tags: javascript, mobile, cordova

i'd like to collect information about how customers use an application I developed. The goal is to improve the user experience and understand what people are using the most.

From previous experience I understand that there are two options - either to call ad-hok URLs that collect states / events / pages / clicks using or to aggregate the information in a local storage and push it back to the server when possible.

Are there already made solutions for Mobile apps? Something that is written in JavaScript that I can plug in easily?

Answer (score 0):

Use flurry or mixpanel.

http://www.flurry.com/

https://mixpanel.com/

Comment: thanks, any comparison to https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ ?

Comment: Well, google analytics is free :) Also, they're easily the biggest player out there. But the other 2 have been into the 'mobile' analytics space for quite some time. Still overall i think GA might be a better option. Stupid of me to have not mentioned in my answer.